# Centering text(String) in a surface view

Tags: android, string, canvas, surfaceview, centering

How do you horizontally center a String in a surface view?

I don't want

```
c.drawText(""+score, c.getWidth()/2, y);
```

Because this will display text starting at the center of the screen.

I want something like

```
c.drawText(""+score, c.getWidth()/2-score.length()/2*fontSize, y);
```

Is there an equation to solve this problem?  If not, are there any other ways to center text in a surface view?

*BTW I'm using a custom font, I don't know if that changes anything or not.  If you need to know any extra information about the font please comment.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to calculate manually. You just need to specify some extra parameters in your [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(textColor); 
paint.setTextSize(28); 
paint.setTypeface(typeface); 
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

The key is that you need to specify **Align.CENTER**, in this way you can just call:

```
canvas.drawText("CENTERED TEXT", canvas.getWidth()/2, posY, paint);
```